# Django Query input results of one queryset to find an object that doesn't appear in another model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

Good afternoon,

I am trying to write an DRF endpoint that returns the next unused hint.

I have two models:

```
class GameActivity(models.Model):
    activity_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='activity_user')
    activity_type = models.ForeignKey(GameActivityType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='game_activity_type')
    activity_hint = models.ForeignKey(Hint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="hint_activity"))
```

And

```
class Hint(models.Model):
    hint_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hint_detail = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    hint_level = models.IntegerField()
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="chapter_hint")
    pts_cost = models.IntegerField()
```

What I am trying to do is return the next hint for the passed in Chapter ID that is NOT in the GameActivity model.

pseudo-code
return Hint where (Count (GameActivity where activity_hint=Hint AND Hint.Chapter == Chapter.ID) = 0) order by hint_level ASC LIMIT 1

I cannot figure out how to chain two queries together, the first being input to the second.

Queryset = SELECT * from Hint WHERE chapter.id = CHAPTER_ID

Pass in the queryset into GameActivity and return the one Hint with the lowest  hint_level that doesn't have a GameActivity entry.

Thanks for any help, I feel like I am not thinking about the problem correctly.

EDIT:  So I realized that the answer given was exactly what I asked for.  However, I messed up my question.  The answer accepted returns the next Hint without a reference in the log as requested, but I need to it return the next Hint without reference for that user.

I tried to modify the query to:

```
queryset = Hint.objects.filter(hint_activity=None, chapter__url_key=chapter_uuid, hint_activity__user=curr_user).order_by('hint_level').first()
```

and

```
queryset = Hint.objects.filter( hint_activity__user=curr_user).filter(hint_activity=None, chapter__url_key=chapter_uuid, hint_activity__user=curr_user).order_by('hint_level').first()
```

Note: I added a reverse name to the GameActivity FK (related_name="hint_activity").

curr_user is the current logged in user making the call:

```
curr_user = self.request.user
```

Neither of these methods are returning any results.

Thanks for any help.

BCBB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this with:

```
Hint.objects.filter(gameactivity=None, chapter_id=my_chapter_id).order_by(
    'hint_level'
).first()
```

this will return a `Hint` not referred to by any `GameActivity` for a given `capter_id`, and with the lowest `hint_level`. If there is no such item, `None` is returned.

Comment: Thanks!  This did the trick for me, much appreciated.

Comment: OK, so I missed concept.  It's not just that there needs to be no entries in the log, but no entries by that User.  I tried to add to the filter as edited above but I get no results.  The initial works great when testing with no user, but with multiple users, it returns the next Hint that NO ONE has accessed yet instead of just in the context of that user.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @BringCoffeeBringBeer: so it should not be accessed by the login user? What about `Hint.objects.filter(chapter_id=my_chapter_id).exclude(gameactivity__user=request.user).order_by('hint_level').first()`?

Comment: It should just be for the logged in user.  Apologies if I am not articulating well.  The logged in user should get a next Hint if there is no log entry of them getting that hint for that chapter.

Comment: @BringCoffeeBringBeer: and that does not work with `Hint.objects.filter(chapter_id=my_chapter_id).exclude(gameactivity__user=request.user).order_by('hint_level').first()` (so use `.exclude(..)` on the `gameactivity__user=request.user`?

Comment: Worked perfectly once I tested it correctly....  It is one of THOSE days!  Thanks so much for your help.